# How to find out character limit based on line number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this structure:

```
<div class="more desc-container">
    <div>
        Some description, which might be really long
    </div>
</div>
```

And I have the following Javascript code:

```
var ellipsestext = "...";
var moretext = "Read More";
var lesstext = "View Less";

function initializeMore() {
    this.shortText = $($(this).children("div")[0]).html();
    this.suffix = "";
    var rowNumber = 2;
    if ($(this).hasClass("desc-container")) {
        rowNumber = 4;
    }
    var textContext = $($(this).children("div")[0]);
    while (Math.floor(textContext.height() / textContext.css("lineHeight").replace("px", "")) > rowNumber) {

        this.suffix = this.shortText.substring(this.shortText.length - 1) + this.suffix;
        this.shortText = this.shortText.substring(0, this.shortText.length - 1);
        textContext.html(this.shortText);
    }

    if (this.suffix.length > 0) {
        $(this).append('<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext+ '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + this.suffix + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>');
    } 
}

function handleMoreClicks() {
    ($(this).hasClass("less") ? $(this).removeClass("less").text(moretext) : $(this).addClass("less").text(lesstext)).prev().toggle().parent().prev().toggle();
    return false;
}

//read more link
$(document).ready(function() {    

    $('.more').each(initializeMore);

    $(".morelink").click(handleMoreClicks);
});
```

As you can see, I have a while with the following condition:

```
Math.floor(textContext.height() / textContext.css("lineHeight").replace("px", "")) > rowNumber
```

which always gets the actual `height` of `textContext` and its `lineHeight` and compares their ratio to `rowNumber`. If the ratio is higher than `rowNumber`, then I migrate a character from `this.shortText` to `this.suffix` and change the `html`. However, despite the fact that this works, this is a very poor solution. The question is:

*Is there a bullet-proof way to find out how many characters are needed to be migrated?*

EDIT:

Since I have been asked to provide a fiddle, [I have created one](https://jsfiddle.net/c0gp8w2b/).
I have measured just the cycle and the results were: 211, 198, 191, 191, 196. That's 197.4 milliseconds on average. If we have 5 such divs to handle, then it will keep the browser busy for a second.

Comment: Why is this a poor solution ? Do you have any performance / behavior issue ? Maybe a jsFiddle would help

Comment: @Brewal, the solution is poor, since it has a cycle which does a calculation on every iteration to check whether the number of rows is still too many and in each iteration it changes the html, which is a high-cost operation. Now, imagine very long texts. Off course this can be optimized to use binary search (first migrating half the text and then see whether it was too much or not enough), but that would convert the algorithm to logaritmic instead of linear. The desirable solution would be to determine the desired number of characters to migrate with a formula, rather than a cycle.

Comment: @Brewal, I am in the middle of something, but will create a fiddle the next time I have some spare time if there is no answer by then.

Comment: @Brewal, I have added a fiddle

Comment: why not use css with `overflow` and `text-overflow`?

Comment: @yoavmatchulsky, because instead of using a work-around I would like to keep the design.

Comment: As you said, the only way to make this more efficient is to use a binary search. I don't think you could rely on a magic formula as chars have not a constant width (besides the fact that it also vary depending of the browser).
Another solution would be to wrap each word into spans and get the first word that have a position out of the limits.

Comment: @Brewal, I have mentioned binary search as a slight improvement, but did not state that it is the only way to make it more efficient. There is also the possibility to learn the starting point of the binary search by approximating the probable number of characters that are enough before starting the binary search. I am not convinced that there is no even better solution, hence my question. Wrapping each word into spans would be an overkill and would add unnecessary nodes to the HTML tree.

Comment: Yep, I don't think I can help you here. I'm not even sure SO is the place to ask this kind of question. Maybe code review suits better. Anyway, there's a quite good wiki page about [line wrapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_wrap_and_word_wrap#Algorithm)

Comment: @Brewal, I am not asking about what is wrong in my code. I already know what's wrong. My question is whether there is a formula, or something close to it. As neither of us knows the answer, neither of us is able to respond it. If someone knows for sure that this is not possible and can point out why, then that is an answer as well, which could help future visitors, who want to do something similar. If I absolutely have to do a binary search, but can avoid calling .html in each iteration, then the function would be very quick.

Comment: @Brewal, so a formula, something like f(width, height, text, fontType) returning the number of rows needed, that would already mean a great improvement of the code. So this is not a code-review question, but rather about whether it is possible to determine the number of rows needed for a given text.

Comment: Well, it's quite hard to build such a function without rendering anything as you will have cross browser compatibility issues. Another idea would be to get **uniques** chars in your text, render each char in a box and map their respective width in an array. Then it might be faster to work only with integers, especially for a long text.

Comment: @Brewal, cross-browser issues can be handled by separate code for each browser group It is hard, no doubt about that. That uniques idea is not bad at all, but unfortunately it is not dynamic. If I change the font then I have to do the same thing again. It would make sense to measure each character of different fonts (hopefully not on different pt sizes as well) and store their value and to write an API to do this, but I doubt my client would pay me for a month solely for this work. I wonder whether it is possible in a less labor-intensive way.

Comment: You could make this dynamic by rendering each char into the dom. It wouldn't be that clean, but yet it is a solution. Here is [a start](https://jsfiddle.net/c0gp8w2b/1/) that doesn't take into account line breaks.

Comment: Thanks Brewal, will think this further and hopefully there will be a solution.